# Woocommerse Reviews show after Tabs

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Woocommerce Review section show after Tabs section. Now it's showing Tab.

Ex :
Now :  Description | Extra tab | Reviews

I want :
Description | Extra tab

---

Reviews (This section show separate)

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

first remove reviews tab, in your **functions.php**:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', '_remove_reviews_tab', 98 );
function _remove_reviews_tab( $tabs ) {
  unset( $tabs[ 'reviews' ] );
  return $tabs;
}
```

then in the **single-product.php** template file, any line you want :D, call **comments_template()** function. If you wish to have reviews tab in specific places, for example after "product tabs" and before "related products", do it with hooks:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', '_show_reviews', 15 );
function _show_reviews() {
  comments_template();
}
```

Comment: This works until you have many comments, if you click on "page 2" of comments, it'll hide the description/other tabs and show reviews pressed up top against tab names.